# Ferramenta de busca para meu site no Google

Tags: html, google, seo

Como incluir um *search* dentro do buscador Google? Teria que incluir uma *meta tag* no meu *site* para que isto apareça no Google?

Um pouco difícil de explicar, por isso irei ilustrar com imagem.

[image: search box]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você não pode garantir que ele apareça. Isto é um critério da Google. Você pode criar as condições para que ele apareça em determinadas situações.

Isto pode ser obtido através do chamado [Sitelinks Search Box](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview). Aí tem a documentação que mostra que é necessário colocar algum código no seu *site*, vai um pouco além da *tag* `meta`.

Comment: boa, achei esse site http://www.conversion.com.br/blog/google-adiciona-caixa-de-pesquisa-em-seus-resultados também, com bastante informações. Obrigado.

Comment: ops, acabei esquecendo. Votado, valeu!