# Erro ao criar "Google Sitelinks"

Tags: rich-snippets, google

Estou implementando um [Google Sitelinks](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) já criei uma `Custom Search Engine` do google para o meu site e consigo fazer pesquisas normalmente pelo 
`URL Publico` porem não adicionei a `Search Box` na página (é obrigatorio? criei esta `custom search engine` porque ela é um pré requisito para criar um `Google Sitelinks`) adicionei o meu site para ser indexado pelo google 
(e já foi indexado, posso encontra-lo nas buscas) e adicionei o seguinte código fornecido pela google (no `<head>`):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">     
{          
    "@context": "http://schema.org",           
    "@type": "WebSite",            
    "url": "http://ricardohenriq.github.io/",              
    "potentialAction": {                 
        "@type": "SearchAction",                 
        "target": "http://ricardohenriq.github.io/search?q={q}",
        "query-input": "required name=q"           
    }       
}           
</script>
```

Porem não está sendo exibido os `Sites Links` na pesquisa quando o meu site é o primeiro posicionado (ele só é 
o primeiro quando insiro o enderço na pesquisa do google).

Link do site: http://ricardohenriq.github.io/

**OBS:** notei que sites como baixaki http://www.baixaki.com.br/ não tem este código `json` exibido acima.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Ferramenta de busca para meu site no Google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56334/ferramenta-de-busca-para-meu-site-no-google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estes sites links geralmente são automáticos e o `json` usado seria apenas para configurar a busca "direcionada interna" (no caso aparece aquele buscador e ele direciona para o buscador do seu site).

Tenho dois clientes que os sites não usam isto e aparece mesmo assim o links (exceto o buscador que não aparece).

A indexação leva algum tempo e a exibição destes links levam mais tempo, até que o Google colete dados para determinar as páginas que irão aparecer, isto é geralmente definido pelas visitas dos usuários as páginas especificas e pelo volume de trafego no seu site.

Não é algo exato e pode levar algum tempo, pois isto ocorre pelo processo do algorítimo do Google e ele "constantemente" muda a forma de trabalhar.

Outro motivo que pode levar a demora é que geralmente isto entra em uma fila de revisão, assim como ocorre nos anúncios pagos.

Resumindo, conforme o trafego aumentar e as buscas no Google por conteúdo que apontar o seu site, mais chances de aparecer os *sitelinks*.

[Conforme o Google:](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=pt)

> Exibimos links de sites nos resultados somente quando achamos que eles podem ser úteis para o usuário. Se a estrutura de seu site não permitir que nossos algoritmos localizem bons links de site ou se você achar que os links para seu site não são pertinentes para a consulta do usuário, nós não os exibiremos.
>
> No momento, os sitelinks são automatizados. Estamos trabalhando constantemente para melhorar os algoritmos dos sitelinks. É possível que no futuro venhamos a incorporar sugestões e informações fornecidas pelos webmasters. No entanto, existem práticas recomendadas que podem ser seguidas para melhorar a qualidade dos seus sitelinks. Por exemplo, para os links internos do seu site, use textos âncora e textos com atributo alt informativos, compactos e sem repetições.

### Dicas:

- Poste material de "qualidade" referente, como matérias e tutorias.
- Recomendo licenciar os seus textos (usando por exemplo a licensa *creativecommons*, assim se encontrar o seu texto, você pode <s>tentar</s> solicitar para quem copiou fazer uma referencia para a sua página)
- Cuidado com a *troca de links*, se for faze-lo, é aceitável, mas pode causar um impacto negativo se eles perceberem abuso

Comment: Então posso remover o json da página que não haverá ônus algum? e nem colocar a barra de pesquisa no site?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique apenas a barra de pesquisa não irá funcionar (aquela barra que aparece acima dos links), sim pode remover, mas a vantagem dele é configurar a busca se houver.

Comment: Ok, irei deletar minha conta pra não de dar os pontos. =D

Comment: @RicardoHenrique KkKkkkk :) Levei um baita susto. Não pelos pontos, mas por um segundo pensei que você iria deixar a comunidade kkkk - Afinal bons colaborares que nem você, não é todo dia que tem na comunidade. Até mais.