# Definir links de site - Pesquisa no Google

Tags: google, seo

é possível definir ordem dos links que aparecem na busca do google na parte onde ele lista 6 links?

[image: São esses links do retângulo vermelho]

Comment: Isso se chama [**SiteLinks**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68010/erro-ao-criar-google-sitelinks), só sites com um numero elevado de visitas costumam exibir isto, as vezes também sendo exibido em consultas direcionadas (quando o google nota que o usuário visita muito o site determinado e então exibe os links para facilitar)

Comment: Acredito que essa ordem seja por relevância.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento usando Rich Snippets e Schema.Org, vc consegue com que o Google te mostre dessa forma no resultado da pesquisa.

Comment: @hugocsl sim, eu sei, mas só mostra uma possibilidade, não garante que isto será exibido a todos usuários do google.

Comment: Repare que não tem a barra de Search no resultado da pesquisa! Ex: https://marketplace.webkul.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sitelinksearch-without-markup.png aqui tem a Search Bar. A dele não tem...

Comment: @hugocsl isso é uma opção adicional que você pode configurar, e também só será exibida conforme o Google achar necessário, dentro daquilo que eu já citei no primeiro comentário: 1. sites com muitas visitas 2. consultar direcionadas. Outro detalhe é o tempo de indexação, que pode levar meses, no link que deixei como dup esta explicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível alterar a ordem dos *sitelinks*, ela se ajusta conforme a necessidade do usuário, geralmente direcionando os links mais buscados ou mais buscados anteriormente pelo usuário, o que pode variar muito conforme o algorítimo do buscador Google muda, conforme respondi em [*Erro ao criar “Google Sitelinks”*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70395/3635)

Conforme a propria [**Google**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=pt):

> Exibimos **sitelinks** de resultados somente quando achamos que eles podem ser úteis para o usuário. Se a estrutura de seu site não permitir que nossos algoritmos localizem bons links de site ou se você achar que os links para seu site não são pertinentes para a consulta do usuário, nós não os exibiremos.
>
> No momento, os sitelinks são automatizados. Estamos trabalhando constantemente para melhorar os algoritmos dos sitelinks. **É possível que no futuro venhamos a incorporar sugestões e informações fornecidas pelos webmasters.** No entanto, existem práticas recomendadas que podem ser seguidas para melhorar a qualidade dos seus sitelinks. Por exemplo, para os links internos do seu site, use textos âncora e textos com atributo alt informativos, compactos e sem repetições.

Ou seja a parte que fala:

> É possível que no futuro venhamos a incorporar sugestões e informações fornecidas pelos webmasters.

Ela afirma que talvez no futuro o webmaster (você) possa fazer algo para controlar os links/sugestões, mas até o momento **os sitelinks são automatizados.**

Também vale notar que os sitelinks só são exibidos conforme o algorítimo achar necessário/útil ao usuário. Ou seja pode até mostrar, mas os sitelinks podem variar para cada usuário, mostrando o que o algorítimo acredita ser útil para cada usuário especifico.